# show 1 is not a linear combination of the polynomials 2 and x in Z[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that 1 is not a linear combination of the polynomials 2 and x in Z[x], can you give any hints for this?

What I have done is construct $f(x), g(x) \in Z[x]$ such that

\begin{align}
2f(x) + x g(x)=1
\end{align}

Let 
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k a_n x^n, \quad g(x) = \sum_{m=0}^l b_m x^m
\end{align}
where $a_n, b_n \in Z$, collecting coefficient terms, I see that 
\begin{align}
2 a_0 = 1
\end{align}
and this is impossible since $a_0 \in Z$.

I want to know some other proof

Are there any other proofs?

Comment: Linear combinations of $2$ and $x$ are always even at $x=0$ (which is essentially what you've done).

Comment: You haven't constructed $f$ and $g$, you've assumed their existence, for contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $2f(x) + x g(x)=1$ for some $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$, then $\frac{1}{2}=f(0) \notin \mathbb Z$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If it were true, then $(x,2)=(1)$ which would give $$\Bbb Z_2\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x,2)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(1)\cong \{0\}$$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are no polynomials $f,g$ with integer coefficients such that $xf(x)+2g(x)=1$,
since the constant coefficient on the left-hand side is divisible by 2.